# How to retrieve data from extended user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to make a simple signup/login page through django.
I have used UserCreationForm and used a model UserProfile to extend the user model.
I want to retrieve the data posted from form i.e department at my home page after user logged in.
I am new to django so brief explanation would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from mysite.core.models import UserProfile
from django.db import models

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    department = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email','password1', 'password2', 'department',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user_profile = UserProfile(user=user, department=self.cleaned_data['department'])
        user.save()
        user_profile.save()
        return user, user_profile
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from mysite.core.forms import SignUpForm

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user,user_profile = form.save(commit=False)
            username = user.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = user.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

home.html in templates:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Welcome, <small>{{ user.username }}</small>!</h2>
<p>Your email address: {{ user.email }}</p>
<p>Department: {{ user_profile.department }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I am able to print username and email but department is coming empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have the wrong relationship. There is a one-to-one relationship between User and UserProfile; a user can only have one profile, and a profile can only belong to one user. The way you have it now, a user can have many profiles, which doesn't make sense.

You should replace the ForeignKey with a OneToOneField.

Once you have done that, you will be able to access the profile data via the relationship: `user.userprofile.department`, and so on.